# TestFX 4: Can't use simply verifyThat(), have to use the whole import name

Tags: java, javafx, testfx

I suspect there is something weird going on in my project setup. When I try to just use the method `verifyThat()` the compiler can't find it and I get an error in my program, but when I write out the whole thing, `org.loadui.testfx.Assertions.verifyThat()`, it works. I am importing like this: `import org.loadui.testfx.*;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to import static (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

```
import static org.loadui.testfx.Assertions.*;
```

This will import all the public static symbols from the Assertions class, whereas your import only imports the class.

```
Assertions.verifyThat()
```

Should also work in your code.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Guess I'll have to read up on static imports then.